# Firefox moves extensions around when enabling/disabling

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions, browser-addons

When I enable or disable Firefox extensions, they change position after about a second (or less, didn't time it).  This is a problem when I am trying to figure out what extension broke a site by disabling groups of them (binary search).

Is there a way to increase the time period before the extension moves between the enabled and disabled groups?

Answer (score 0):

You can *keep* a disabled add-on in its place in the list until the page, *about:addons*, is reloaded.

Open *about:config*, and change the value of `services.sync.addons.ignoreUserEnabledChanges` to *true* by double-clicking it.

Of course, set to *false* to revert to the behavior where the item jumps to the *Diabled* list.

Comment: This also disables the syncing of add-on states [link](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Services/Sync/Addon_Sync#Can_I_have_different_enabled_states_on_different_machines.3F)

Comment: @AlexO, yes, but it states, "f this preference is set to true, all add-on installs will be installed in the enabled state. However, you can immediately disable the add-on and incoming enabled state changes won't be applied. " If I understand correctly, then the change to disable *is* accepted immediately, but the next time Firefox starts, the add-on is enabled...